# How can i show it at first?

Tags: java, split, stringtokenizer

I wrote a simple java application, I have a problem please help me;

I have a file  (JUST EXAMPLE):

```
1.TXT
-------
SET MRED:NAME=MRED:0,MREDID=60;
SET BCT:NAME=BCT:0,NEPE=DCS,T2=5,DK0=KOR;
CREATE LCD:NAME=LCD:0;
-------
```

and this is my source code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

class test1 {

    private final int FLUSH_LIMIT = 1024 * 1024;
    private StringBuilder outputBuffer = new StringBuilder(
            FLUSH_LIMIT + 1024);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        test1 p=new test1();
        String fileName = "i:\\1\\1.txt";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ";|,");
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String token = st.nextToken();
                p.processToken(token);

            }
        }
        p.flushOutputBuffer();
    }

    private void processToken(String token) {
        if (token.startsWith("MREDID=")) {
            String value = getTokenValue(token,"=");
            outputBuffer.append("MREDID:").append(value).append("\n");
        } else if (token.startsWith("DK0=")) {
            String value = getTokenValue(token,"=");
            outputBuffer.append("DK0=:").append(value).append("\n");
        } else if (token.startsWith("NEPE=")) {
            String value = getTokenValue(token,"=");
            outputBuffer.append("NEPE:").append(value).append("\n");
        }
        if (outputBuffer.length() > FLUSH_LIMIT) {
            flushOutputBuffer();
        }
    }

    private String getTokenValue(String token,String find) {
        int start = token.indexOf(find) + 1;
        int end = token.length();
        String value = token.substring(start, end);
        return value;
    }

    private void flushOutputBuffer() {
        System.out.print(outputBuffer);
        outputBuffer = new StringBuilder(FLUSH_LIMIT + 1024);
    }

}
```

I want this output :

```
MREDID:60
DK0=:KOR
NEPE:DCS
```

But this application show me this :

```
MREDID:60
NEPE:DCS
DK0=:KOR
```

please tell me how can i handle this , because of that DK0 must be at first and this is just a sample ; my real application has 14000 lines

Thanks ...

Comment: From the comment on my answer, I'm guessing I don't completely understand the problem you're trying to solve. Do you expect MREDID, DK0 and NEPE to appear more than once in your file, and do yo want to print them all? Are there in fact a bigger number of unique tokens you want printed in a specific order and the three in your source code is there only as an example?

Comment: yes exactly ; could you help me please ...

Comment: In that case I'm assuming that mredid, nepe and dk0 might occur several times. Do you want to print them in the following manner: mredid, dk0, nepe, mredid, dk0, nepe... or mredid, mredid, dk0, dk0, nepe, nepe? Please edit your question, maybe with a slightly bigger example txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of outputting the value when you read it, put it in a hashmap. Once you've read your entire file, output in the order you want by getting the values from the hashmap.

Comment: Nice call!  I generally tune out when an American, who writes like a third-worlder, doesn't even explain what he is trying to do with his program.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class, something like

```
class data {
   private int mredid;
   private String nepe;
   private String dk0;

   public void setMredid(int mredid) {
      this.mredid = mredid;
   }

   public void setNepe(String nepe) {
      this.nepe = nepe;
   }

   public void setDk0(String dk0) {
      this.dk0 = dk0;
   }

   public String toString() {
      String ret = "MREDID:" + mredid + "\n";
      ret = ret + "DK0=:" + dk0 + "\n";
      ret = ret + "NEPE:" + nepe + "\n";
   }
```

Then change processToken to

```
private void processToken(String token) {
    Data data = new Data();
    if (token.startsWith("MREDID=")) {
        String value = getTokenValue(token,"=");
        data.setMredid(Integer.parseInt(value));
    } else if (token.startsWith("DK0=")) {
        String value = getTokenValue(token,"=");
        data.setDk0(value);
    } else if (token.startsWith("NEPE=")) {
        String value = getTokenValue(token,"=");
        data.setNepe(value);
    }
    outputBuffer.append(data.toString());
    if (outputBuffer.length() > FLUSH_LIMIT) {
        flushOutputBuffer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but as I message ; my application has 14000 lines and setter not good for it ...

Answer (score 0):

Use a [HashTable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) to store the values and print from it in the desired order after parsing all tokens.

```
//initialize hash table
HashTable ht = new HashTable();

//instead of outputBuffer.append, put the values in to the table like
ht.put("NEPE", value);
ht.put("DK0", value); //etc

//print the values after the while loop
System.out.println("MREDID:" + ht.get("MREDID"));
System.out.println("DK0:" + ht.get("DK0"));
System.out.println("NEPE:" + ht.get("NEPE"));
```